# PreparedStatement getGeneratedKeys() JDBC

Tags: sql, jdbc, insert, prepared-statement

i used getGeneratedKeys after inserting in Batchmode. I presume that the order i with the keys are returned is the same as the inserts in my batched insert statments. I want to use the keys as foreign keys in an other table and need to map the data to the foreign key.

1. Is this correct? The API doesn't say anything about the order... :-(
2. What happens if I do "insert ignore", do I have to calulate the offset from the executeBatch()-Function? Or is there an easier way to map generated keys and inserted data in my java app?

Thanks soooo much guys. I'm happy for any hint.

Comment: * If the primary key is an auto-increment, how could an "insert ignore" possibly find a duplicate and ignore the insert?
* executeBatch() returns an array of rows affected. Should there be a 0 in there then that would indicate that there is no generated key to be found.
* Not so sure you will get any generated keys from a batch insert.